# Не подгружается скрипт после ajax

Tags: ajax

Такая проблема. После перезагрузки всего сайта сделанного на ajax скрипт в записи работает. А после открытия в отдельно ajax (аудиопоста) скрипт видимо не подгружается и действие не работает. Я чайник, уже второй день сижу. Но очень надо. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот вся конструкция

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find('.download-animate-link').mousemove(function (e) {
    var animate_time = 800;
    if($(this).attr('animate-time') != undefined && $(this).attr('animate- 
    time') != '') {
    var animate_time = $(this).attr('animate-time');
    }
    console.log(animate_time);
    $('.animate-height').animate({height: "80px", padding: "25px", display: 
    "block"}, animate_time, function () {
    $('.animate-height span').show();
     });
     });
     })</script>  

    <div class="animate-height" style="height: 0px; padding: 25px">
    <span style="display: inline;">
    </span>
    </div> 

    <script async 
    src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- verh sita -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block" data-ad-client="ca-pub- 
    51050" data-ad-slot="2898431558" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width- 
    responsive="true">
    </ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>

     <?php
     if ($itunes != null) {
     echo '
     <center><div class="SideAdMpu ad-article adSpace12 adSpace16 
     ad_sidebar3 kdz_ad2 sideAd ad ads adsense-adserver- /adconfig/ad 
   /advertisment- /jsadscripts/ad /pagepeelads. /ysmads. _ad_view= 
    _popunder. -468x80- _486x60.
    "><a href="' . $itunes . '"
     class="download-link-zippy z-external-link download-animate-link"
     data-block-id="18254" data-link="' . $itunes . '" animate-time="800" 
     rel="nofollow,noindex" target="_blank" data-ab="" title="Сохранить 
    ссылку как ... Правой кнопкой мыши ..."><b>СКАЧАТЬ ЭТО РАДИОШОУ</div> 
    </a></div></b></div><br></div></center>';
    }
    ?>
```

тарабарщина в div в ссылке это для адблока он блокирует кнопку скачать

Comment: А где ajax?Чёт не нахожу...может много всего...выделите хоть жирным.

Comment: этот код в теле аудиопоста в отдельной записи singl-audio.php тут без моего сайта не обойтись. Посмотрите сами. Просто отключите все блокираторы рекламы и увидите ссылку наведя на неё мышкой и все поймете. Но надо открыть запись, пост и перегрузить страницу иначе код не подгрузится. В коде страницы записи все видно, и то, что я написал здесь. Сайт - trancemuz точка ру